# WooCommerce variation increment quantity acts directly on the cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce and for the variable product, with variations, I have a choose option, when user chooses an option, they can click on add to cart, and it adds it to the cart, as supposed. But I have also a quantity which you can increment or decrement and if I click on plus or minus it adds or removes the quantity direct to or from the cart, I want only the product only gets added to the cart after clicking on add to cart (submit).

This is what I have in the functions.php in the child theme.

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', 'ajax_add_to_cart');

function ajax_add_to_cart() {
    check_ajax_referer('ajax_add_to_cart_nonce', 'nonce');

    if (isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']);
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
        die();
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'cart_fragments');

function cart_fragments($fragments) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="cart-contents"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
    <?php
    $fragments['span.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

And this is the variations add to cart:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;
?>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <div class="quantity">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>">my-quantity</label>
        <div class="quantity_deel">
            <div class="plus-min-btns">
                <button onclick="decrementQuantity()">-</button>
                <input type="number" id="quantity_<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="input-text qty text" name="quantity" value="1" aria-label="Product quantity" size="4" min="1" step="1" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off">
                <button onclick="incrementQuantity()">+</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
</div>

<script>
    function decrementQuantity() {
        var quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity_<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>");
        var currentValue = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
        if (currentValue > 1) {
            quantityInput.value = currentValue - 1;
        }
    }

    function incrementQuantity() {
        var quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity_<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>");
        var currentValue = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
        quantityInput.value = currentValue + 1;
    }
</script>
```

Can someone explain why is this not working?

Comment: Your current provided code has nothing to do with that issue. There is some other code somewhere else, that adds or removes the quantity directly to or from the cart… It can be some other code added by you, it can be a 3rd party plugin or even your theme.

Comment: It was in the variotions variation-add-to-cart-button.php in the woocommerce / single-product/ add to cart folder and I had to add this code; and added the proper script under the file. That did the work for me. Apoligizes for being unclear.